# TCP Server and Client java

Tags: java, networking, tcp

I'm new at Java and have been having some issues while passing a variable from one class to another main class.

**A little about the program -** 
I have one main class called "Server.java" and another main class called "Client.java"

This is a simple TCP Server-client program written in java. The server class is executed first so it can accept connection from the client, which is executed second.
Once the client is connected to the server, the client specifies the name of the file it wishes to receive from the server by typing, for instance, "alice.txt" and then the server sends the file with that name in it's directory to the client.

**Where I'm stuck -**  
I'm only able to receive file on the client side if I hard code the name of the file first in the server (check the code below). I wish to take the file name from the client side and pass to the Server class so the code works for all the files and not just one, which was hard coded.

Any help is appreciated :)

**Server.java**

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 

class Server 
{   
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
{
    //beginning of the try method
    try
    {

        //create a new serversocket object with port no 6789
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

        //while loop
        while(true)          
        {           
            //create a new socket object and accept the connection and it waits for any connection from client
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

            //display confirmation to the user
            System.out.println("Connection accepted!");
            System.out.println("File request recevied!");

            //specify the file the server wants to send
            File myFile = new File("alice.txt"); 
//THIS IS WHERE THE FILE FROM THE CLIENT IS HARD-CODED. I AM TRYING TO REPLACE THE FILE NAME WITH A VARIABLE THAT WAS PASSED FROM THE CLIENT SIDE

            //get the byte array length of the file
            byte [] bArray = new byte [(int)myFile.length()]; 

            //open a new file object
            FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(myFile);

            //new buffered input stream object
            BufferedInputStream bs = new BufferedInputStream(f);

            //read  function of the inputput stream
            bs.read(bArray, 0, bArray.length);

            //declare new output strea object
            OutputStream os = connectionSocket.getOutputStream();

            //display messages to the users
            System.out.println("Okay, sending the file now.");

            //write the file
            os.write(bArray, 0, bArray.length);

            //flush the file
            os.flush();

            //close the connection
            connectionSocket.close();

            //display confirmation message to the user
            System.out.println("File was successfully sent!");

        }       
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

**Client.java**

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 
import java.util.*;


class Client 
{  
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception  
{   
    try
    {
        //declare scanner object
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        //display a message to the user
        System.out.println("Enter the file name you wish to request");

        //read the user input 
        String textFileName = s.nextLine();

        //declare a new Socket object and specify the host name and the port number
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789); 

        //make a byte array in which the transmitted file will be broken down into and sent
        byte [] bArray = new byte[10000000];

        //create new inputstream object and set it to the input stream from the client
        InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();

        //open new fileinput object
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(textFileName);

        //get the value from the fileoutputstream to bufferedoutput stream
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        //read function of the inputsteam object
        int readFile = is.read(bArray,0,bArray.length);

        //assign readfile to endile
        int endFile = readFile;

        do
        {
            readFile = is.read(bArray, endFile, (bArray.length-endFile));

            if(readFile >= 0)
            {
                endFile = endFile + readFile;
            }

        }while(readFile > -1);

        //write file
        bos.write(bArray, 0, endFile);

        //show the message to the user
        System.out.println("File " + textFileName + " was successfully received!");

        //flush the file
        bos.flush();

        //close the file
        bos.close();

        //close the socket
        clientSocket.close();

        ///

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

Comment: If you're calling this program from the command line, just pass it as an argument then grab it from the parameter to main by using argv[0] or argv[1] etc

Comment: @Fallso I did that but got stuck when it came to pass those arguments to Server.java. Also had a look at getters and setters, but from what I learned, they are not applicable to Main classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I would do :
PS : this has not been tested but the principle is here..

**Server.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Server 
{   
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {
        //beginning of the try method
        try
        {

            //create a new serversocket object with port no 6789
            ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

            //while loop
            while(true)          
            {
                //create a new socket object and accept the connection and it waits for any connection from client
                Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();// TODO - Make a new thread after the connection is accepted

                //display confirmation to the user
                System.out.println("Connection accepted!");

                // Recover the fileName from client
                String fileName = "";
                InputStream iS = connectionSocket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader iSR = new InputStreamReader(iS);
                BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(iSR);
                fileName = bR.readLine();
                System.out.println("File request received : " + fileName);

                // Recover the file's byte array
                File myFile = new File(fileName);
                byte[] bArray = new byte[(int)myFile.length()];
                FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                BufferedInputStream bs = new BufferedInputStream(f);
                bs.read(bArray, 0, bArray.length);

                //display messages to the users
                System.out.println("Okay, sending the file now.");

                //declare new output strea object
                OutputStream os = connectionSocket.getOutputStream();
                os.write(bArray, 0, bArray.length);
                os.flush();

                //close the connection
                connectionSocket.close();

                //display confirmation message to the user
                System.out.println("File was successfully sent!");

            }       
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 
import java.util.*;


class Client 
{  
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception  
    {   
        try
        {
            //declare scanner object
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

            //display a message to the user
            System.out.println("Enter the file name you wish to request");

            //read the user input 
            String textFileName = s.nextLine();

            //declare a new Socket object and specify the host name and the port number
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);

            // Send the filename via the connection
            OutputStream oS = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bW = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(oS));
            bW.write(textFileName);

            //make a byte array in which the transmitted file will be broken down into and sent
            byte[] bArray = new byte[10000000];

            //create new inputstream object and set it to the input stream from the client
            InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();

            //open new fileinput object
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(split[1]);

            //get the value from the fileoutputstream to bufferedoutput stream
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

            //read function of the inputsteam object
            int readFile = is.read(bArray,0,bArray.length);

            //assign readfile to endile
            int endFile = readFile;

            do
            {
                readFile = is.read(bArray, endFile, (bArray.length-endFile));

                if(readFile >= 0)
                {
                    endFile = endFile + readFile;
                }
            }while(readFile > -1);

            //write file
            bos.write(bArray, 0, endFile);

            //show the message to the user
            System.out.println("File " + textFileName + " was successfully received!");

            //flush the file
            bos.flush();

            //close the file
            bos.close();

            //close the socket
            clientSocket.close();

            ///

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Hybris95,
I made a little change to your code by adding bW.newLine(); and bW.flush(); after bW.write(textFileName);

and it worked perfectly! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, once connection established, client expecting something from server using InputStream, and server sending data to client using OutputStream. but you have to do in this way, once connection established, in client code, write filename to server using OutputStream and then read data from server, similarly, in server side first read something from client and then write something to client as you did.